# Is there a good J2ME IDE?

Tags: java, ide, java-me

Is there a good J2ME IDE? I mean something lightweight, and portable. Something that can run what you program on it. My favorite Java IDE is JCreator Lite. Is there something like that for J2ME? Also, which would you say is the best J2ME IDE?

Answer (score 20):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/javame/index.html) is quite good, albeit not very lightweight.
[This tutorial](http://www.defza.com/wordpress/development/j2me-tutorial) offers a good illustration.

[image]

Comment: I'm married to Eclipse and would hate to have to switch to Netbeans but it is a fact that any new work Sun releases for J2ME first appears on Netbeans and there's a delay before it gets adapted to Eclipse. In practice this has never been a problem for me but it may be more of a consideration depending on what you do/where you work.

Comment: Netbeans, though it is bit heavier and will be sluggish once you start using the inbuilt pre-processing modules, is far better compared to Eclipse MTJ in managing different configuration and screen resolutions in a single source.

Answer (score 7):

The Eclipse plugin [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/) (now [Mobile Tools for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/)) is very good and integrates well with SDKs from device manufacturers.  I've used it for development on Sony Ericsson devices and it lets you do things like on-device debugging from within the IDE.

Answer (score 6):

You are having two options. Netbeans and Eclipse ,But i don't think both are lightweight ,they are heavyweight champions actually.   Considering J2ME netbeans is very good platform to start with. Its having easy to set up configurations for J2ME and nowadays everything is bundled to netbeans package.

---

Then you have Eclipse which is equally good and widely used .Eclipse is having new MTJ(Mobile Tools for Java) package for J2ME which has made many tasks easier than before. Its emerging as a ideal IDE for many languages and frameworks. As an IDE you have more benefits for Eclipse compared to Netbeans .

Anyway you have to try both select the one which you find comfortable .

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans IDE & Eclipse IDE are the best two environments to work for developing JavaME applications.

The only difference which I found out between the two IDE when I coded on JavaME was that for NetBeans , J2me environment was already added.

For Eclipse , the developer was required to add the j2me plugin , antenna for building , J2me Wirless toolkits

NetBeans IDE can be downloaded from the following link

**http://netbeans.org/features/javame/**

Eclipse IDE & EclipseME plugin can be downloaded from the following links respectively

**http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/**

**http://eclipseme.org/**

Answer (score 1):

Sun's NetBeans also can support Mac OS X by using [Java ME SDK 3.0 Mac OS X](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30_mac.jsp) version.
That's why I love it.

Answer (score 1):

The Netbeans is not sun's product.

For choosing IDE.1st we decide for which kind of mobile (nokia,samsung,etc) our application is build.Then we goto the vendor from that we get their specific component,sdk,etc.Then we work on SDK is usefull.

Thanks & Regards,
Sivakumar.J