# What are the pros and cons of eclipse vs netbeans vs others for j2me development?

Tags: java, ide, java-me

What are the pros and cons of eclipse vs netbeans vs others for j2me development?

Which would you choose and why?

[edit]
When asking the question [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646431/is-there-a-good-j2me-ide) didn't turn up in the list

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330027/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-and-netbeans-if-i-want-to-use-only-the-jav among many others.

Comment: @ Neil Butterworth - I can't see how it's a duplicate of that specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I would use [NetBeans](http://www.thainetbeans.com/sample/mobile.htm), as mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646431/is-there-a-good-j2me-ide).

Eclipse with its plugin [eclipseme](http://eclipseme.org/docs/news.html), is not as up-to-date than Netbeans on that front, although [Orson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101334/0rson) does mention [DSDP/MTJ -  Mobile Tools for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/), which is [soon to be 1.0](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=dsdp.mtj).
So on eclipse side, the [DSDP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DSDP) (Device Software Development Platform) is in progress, and will include:

- a Device Deebuggin (DD),
- a Target Management,
- MTJ ,
- and a Native Application Builder (NAB) component.

Comment: I think this is meant to replace the outdated eclipseme: http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/

Answer (score 2):

disclaimer: I am an eclipse fanboy

I've used both eclipse and netbeans and personally I prefer eclipse. It's true that I do more than just java development, so the flexibilty of eclipse is what's particularly attractive. The vast array of plugins available for eclipse make it a valuable tool for java, web development, UML modeling, and more.

If *all* you want to do is java development, then I don't think you'll find either to have a significant edge (there are differences but not, in my opinion, significant enough to make or break the choice)

Comment: I'm more interested in specifically j2me development support