# Which IDE should be used for Java Application development?

Tags: java, android, blackberry, java-me, nokia

I want to develop applications for Nokia Mobile. I googled and found that J2ME is the language in which app can be developed for the mobile phone.

Please suggest any IDE in which i can develop applications for Android, Blackberry, Nokia (platforms nokia commonly use) etc.

Is it possible to have a single IDE for all types of development described above?
I work on Microsoft.NET technology and am new to Java Development.

Comment: is it possible to have a single IDE for Nokia, android and blackberry apps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good J2ME IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646431/is-there-a-good-j2me-ide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android I'd go with Eclipse see the following for the Android SDK and Eclipse setup

- [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)
- [Eclipse Plugin for Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
- [Blackberry](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp)
- [Nokia S60](http://developers.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Installing_Java_ME_development_tools_for_S60)

Comment: Ofcourse, for android and blackberry you would go with Eclipse. What about nokia mobiles apps?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Mobile Tools for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/mtj/). It is based on Eclipse and widely used among developers! You can add a large number of plugins to fulfill your needs if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two main used IDEs for Java. Eclipse and Netbeans. Since for Eclipse there is a better plugin for Android, I would recommend it if you want just use one.

Comment: Incorrect.  You make a big mistake by overlooking IntelliJ by JetBrains.  It's better than both Eclipse and NetBeans, in my opinion.  It supports Android and lots more.

Comment: I'll take a look to it but I repeat, I think that eclipse and netbeans have much more users.

Answer (score 0):

There was an eclipse for J2ME (eclipse pulsar). But some people prefer NetBeans.
For Android, eclipse.

This question is not going to live much time, I think XD. Is the kind of 'better' question that gets closed.

Comment: What about nokia mobiles apps?

Comment: For midlets, eclipse pulsar (includes MTJ) or NetBeans. In pulsar it is easy to plug in nokia emulators. If you need to develop for Symbian (that's not java), I don't know. Both J2Me and Symbian are dead, in my opinion XD.

Comment: Actually, it's not really a "better" question for SO. It's not constructive as defined by the FAQ because it has no single answer, will prompt discussion and opinion, and does not involve specific facts. I happen to think it should be closed as not constructive but I haven't flagged it since it is probably fixable. I did however downvote since it wouldn't take much effort on Google to answer almost every question asked and leave a nugget of a passable question.

Comment: @RivieraKid: Its true that it has no single answer but some people can suggest some tools then its up to me which to use. I posted it here because all of you can share ur experiences with the IDE. I mean what problems can arise?

Comment: @himanshu For me it's OK. But read the FAQ for more info. Asking opinions or 'better' questions usually ends with the question closed.